# Padding/margin-inclusive width setting?

Tags: css

Basically I have a div that I want at 100% width. However, I also want it to have some padding. But when I add the padding, the width is added to it, meaning that my div now goes off-screen and there's a horizontal scroll bar.

Usually I compensate by just making the div a lower percentage (like 95%, or 90%).

I was wondering if there are any more elegant ways to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the padding to 5% and width to 90% (100-5x2)

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing).

```
.example {
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
}
```

Per default the width of an element is computed with regard to its content box. So an applied padding is added to the width. If you change the box model to `border-box`, the padding is included in the width. For compatibility have a look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)

Comment: Interesting. Just an observation though, it doesn't seem to have anything for margin.

Comment: I think, the margin is considered outside of the element and thus not part of any box model.

Comment: Not to take away from Vijay, but I think this is the universal answer, especially when you don't know how many cells are going to be in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are four major things involve in CSS Box Model.
i) Margin
ii) Border
iii) Padding
iv) Content

When we set width then we are essentially setting width of CONTENT so adding padding means overall increase of width.

Please go through following resources and you'll get to know everything.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

And you can handle this situation using % or even if you calculate px width correctly if you have also set border or even want to set margins.

```
element{
    width: 96%;
    padding: 0 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default a div is `width: auto` which (assuming normal positioning, display and lack of floating) will cause it to fill its container (accounting for margins, padding and border).

Just leave it at `width: auto` instead of setting an explicit or percentage width.

Comment: That works only for elements that are 100% by default, like `div`s. You cannot do the same for other elements like `input` or anything that doesn't expand to 100% by default.

Comment: Since the question refers to divs repeatedly, that isn't an issue.